# javascript regex to match everything between 2 html comment tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to create a regex which will match anything (including line breaks) between 2 html specific comment tags. Here is an example for some html:

```
<!-- build-remove-start -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- build-remove-end -->

<!-- inject:vendor:js -->
<!-- endinject -->
```

I would like to match every thing between `<!-- build-remove-start -->` and `<!-- build-remove-end -->` not including the comment tags (I mean not to remove the comments tags, only what's inside).
I have tried:
`<!-- build-remove-start -->[\s\S]<!-- build-remove-end -->`
But it doesn't work. 
Here is a link to test the regex:
https://regex101.com/r/rV0qG2/2

Comment: Check [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/rV0qG2/3).

Comment: might i suggest actually using the DOM, which can iterate over comment nodes?

Comment: @Eevee, It is for building purposes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `*` after `[\s\S]`.

```
/<!-- build-remove-start -->([\s\S]*?)<!-- build-remove-end -->/gmi
```

Also I recommend adding `?` after `*` so it makes it lazy. This way you can have the example below, othwerise the `this won't be removed` line will be matched.

```
<!-- build-remove-start -->
//remove this
<!-- build-remove-end -->

This won't be removed

<!-- build-remove-start -->
//Remove this
<!-- build-remove-end -->
```

Comment: doesn't this includes the comments tag?

Comment: Why the capture group?

Comment: You only need to replace what's inside the capture group, and not the whole match.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande, it seems that the comments are also falls to the matching pattern, I need it to be excluded.  Here is a demo of your answer https://regex101.com/r/rV0qG2/4

Comment: That's why I added the capture group, yo need to replace the captured group. Or you mean not to remove the comment tags inside the build-remove-start and build-remove-end?

Comment: I mean not to remove the comments tags, only what's inside

Comment: `[\s\S]*?` will inevitably drain the backtracking buffer limit with large HTML code and the code execution will freeze. Use the regex in my comment if you want to have the same effect but avoid backtracking issues.

Comment: @stribizhev, your answer also take in the matching result the comments, is it possible to leave them?

Comment: @vlio20: No idea what the problem is: [grab Capture group 1 like this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/meaZzK?editors=001), isn't it what you need?